# Having problems dockerizing my django project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker

I am following along in the Django for Professionals book and I am stuck at the first chapter where you create a django project and app
using pipenv and then Dockerizing it
when running *docker build .*  I get the following error

`=> ERROR [4/5] RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system`

I ignored that, made a docker-compose.yml file
and ran *docker-compose build*
and got this error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 458, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 502, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 224, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 320, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 121, in resolve
    self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 445, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 339, in resolve
    failure_causes = self._attempt_to_pin_criterion(name, criterion)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 207, in _attempt_to_pin_criterion
    criteria = self._get_criteria_to_update(candidate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 198, in _get_criteria_to_update
    for r in self._p.get_dependencies(candidate):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/provider.py", line 100, in get_dependencies
    return [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/provider.py", line 100, in <listcomp>
    return [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 252, in iter_dependencies
    requires = self.dist.requires() if with_requires else ()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 234, in dist
    self._prepare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 221, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 313, in _prepare_distribution
    return self._factory.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 480, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 503, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 253, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 130, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 163, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 168, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 64, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.1; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

This is my *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

COPY . /code/
```

This is my *docker-compose.yml* file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
    - .:/code
    ports:
    - 8000:8000
```

Comment: That seems like a issue with your ssl conection, i would check if you container is comunicating properly with the internet.
Try something like ping -c 5 8.8.8.8 just to try and narrow the problem a little bit

Comment: Besides, you may consider to upgrade your pip before `pip install pipenv` in your docker file.

Comment: It turns out I had a bad internet connection yes.

Comment: @Mennoō For me, it was due to bad internet connection too. I switched from an ADSL Internet connection to a smartphone (access point) Internet connection and the error got resolved.